# Any tutorials for multiplatform assembler programming (Mac+Win+Nix)?

Tags: assembly, multiplatform

I want to learn assembler, but I really value multiplatform code, and most of the assembler languages and tutorials I've seen only cater to one specific assembler sub-language (either MASM or TASM or YASM) and one specific OS (either Mac or Windows or Linux).

Are there assembler languages and tutorials that work on Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux? I suspect there's some X86 assembler format that GCC recognizes, and GCC is a multiplatform compiler--what would this language be called, and are there tutorials for it?

Also posted on [r/programming](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/105a1p/any_tutorials_for_multiplatform_assembler/).

Comment: "Out of the box" answer from a redditor, look for "Ian Sinclair" assembler books, he explains assembler very simple. I learnt assembler for commodore 64, at Junior High School ;-)

Comment: Why was my question downvoted??

Comment: I dont know who or why your question was downvoted, but, I think its a very good question, & agree that even if there is a reason to be downvoted, the people who downvoted should add a comment on why

Answer (score 2):

For your needs see such as

> nasm (http://www.nasm.us)

And some good "start point" for nasm

1. http://leto.net/writing/nasm.php
2. http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut

Answer (score 2):

**Extended Boring Long Answer**

Im afraid that each assembler has its own pitfalls.

I start my custom pet project programming language (that translates to "C", doesn't generate binary code), and want to make a full compiler, so I  did some quick research on the same topic your as question.

For example, both MASM & NASM target x86 processors, yet, the assembler syntax is different.

You may also consider what Operating System, (not what processor), are you working, you may have to interact with it.

Some assembler books are written ina very electronics point of view, making unnecesarily difficult to learn assembler.

**Prerequisites**

You may want to study some topics, before getting back to assembler. Most of this topics you may already know, but, it may be good to take another read.

(1) (Re) Learn about different number notations, how to manually change a decimal number to & from hexadecimal, octal & binary notations, without using a calculator.

(2) (Re) Learn about how a character is stored, A.S.C.I. & EBDIC & MAC, you may want a printed ASCII chart of characters.

(3) (Re) Learn about boolean & bit, logical, bitwise operations, "AND", "OR", "XOR"

(4) (Re) Learn about memory storage sizes. Giga, Mega, Byte, Word, QWord or LongWord.

(5) (Re) Learn the difference between a signed and an unsigned integer. And how to store different integer numbers in memory storage.

**Quick Short Answer**

Learn the basics of the 3 more used architectures, & the O.S.

(1) Learn the basics, not everything, of a single CPU, example NASM in x86 plus Windows.

(2) Continue with other architecture, example NASM in x86 plus Linux.

(3) Continue with other architecture, example MacIntosh.

(4) Learn to do simple, yet equivalent tasks in the first 2 targets.

(5) Learn to do the same in the third target.

(6) Check the O.S. calls, its not difficult to add 2 numbers & store the result in a register, in any CPU. But, calling a system call that displays a message in a console windows or GUI window may change.

(7) Most assemblers are called "macro-assemblers", allow to use a single line of code that translates to several lines opf code. Use them for a single macro that reads the same in several assemblers, yet, translates different, in each CPU.

(8) Give the kiteh, a tuna can, for the assembler class.

Cheers.